# swift modal segue , prepareForSegue multithreading

Tags: multithreading, swift, segue

I am trying to make a segue (present modal segue) in swift

I call this function (sender is the a button (logIn button))

```
    func getUserAndSave(sender: AnyObject )
{
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: GET_USER_API))
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var hash = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("hash") as String
    var token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("token") as String


    var params = ["hash":hash, "token":token] as Dictionary<String, String>

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    getUser(request) { result in
        switch result
            {
        case let .Error(error):
            print(error)
            // display error message

        case let .Value(boxedUser):
            let user = boxedUser.value
            self.user = user;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show user details", sender: sender)
            }

            // do something with user
        }
    }

}
```

this is the implementation of getUser function (tho whole swift file) the main thing in
this code is the getUser function:

```
typealias JSON = AnyObject
typealias JSONDictionary = Dictionary<String, JSON>
typealias JSONArray = Array<JSON>

final class Box<A> {
let value: A

init(_ value: A) {
    self.value = value
}
}

enum Result<A> {
case Error(NSError)
case Value(Box<A>)
}

enum Gender
{
case FEMALE , MALE

var description : String
{
    switch self
    {
        case .FEMALE: return "FEMALE";
        case .MALE: return "MALE";
    }
}
}

struct User
{
var fullName : String
var email : String
var raking : Int
var gender : Gender
}




func getUser(request: NSURLRequest, callback: (Result<User>) -> ()) {
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, urlResponse, error            in
    // if the response returned an error send it to the callback
    if let err = error {
        callback(.Error(err))
        return
    }

    var jsonErrorOptional: NSError?
    let jsonOptional: JSON! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &jsonErrorOptional) as? NSDictionary

    // if there was an error parsing the JSON send it back
    if let err = jsonErrorOptional {
        callback(.Error(err))
        return
    }
    if let json = jsonOptional as? JSONDictionary
    {
        if let userDic = json["user"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            var fullName = userDic["fullName"] as AnyObject? as? String
            var email = userDic["email"] as AnyObject? as? String
            var ranking = userDic["ranking"] as AnyObject? as? Int
            var tmpGender = userDic["gender"] as AnyObject? as? Int

            var gender : Gender = tmpGender == 1 ?  Gender.FEMALE : Gender.MALE;

            let user = User(fullName: fullName!, email: email!, raking: ranking!, gender: gender);
            callback(.Value(Box(user)))

        }
    }
    callback(.Error(NSError()))
}
task.resume()
}
```

it get called not in the main thread

this is how I call the getUser function

```
        getUser(request) { result in
        switch result
            {
        case let .Error(error):
            print(error)
            // display error message

        case let .Value(boxedUser):
            let user = boxedUser.value
            self.user = user;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("show user details", sender: sender)
            }

            // do something with user
        }
```

this my prepareForSegue function:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
            if(segue.identifier == "show user details")
            {
                if((sender?.isKindOfClass(LogInViewController)) != nil)
                {
                    if(segue.destinationViewController.isKindOfClass(UserInfoViewController))
                    {
                        var sourceVC = sender as LogInViewController
                        var destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as UserInfoViewController

                        if(self.user != nil)
                        {
                            destinationVC.user = self.user;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            print("WARNING!: self.user is NIll");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

when I get to the prepare for segue function the app crashes ! , I tried to send self(LogInViewController) and it crashes too , at the debugger it get stuck on the first line of
prepareForsegue function , what's wrong with this code ? 
sorry for the long code :D

Comment: Just to make sure. Did you create the segue using IB by drag from the button to the destination view controller directly? Because you are trigger the segue programmatically, you should drag from the source view controller to the destination view controller, not from the button. If you already did it, I have not yet found where is the problem.

Comment: no I didn't drag it from button I drag it from source viewController to another